# Calling a class from within a class

Tags: java, string, if-statement, joptionpane

```
String ans = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "S,T,R,K or P?");
if (ans == "S")
{ 
    class Square
}
```

Basically, I'd like to run this exert of code under a main class Shapes, and then in the if statement I'd like to know how to run another separate class inside this class Shapes if possible, i.e.

```
ans = S
```

and then it runs another program which creates a square using text stars "*" in that same Shapes program.

Comment: Use `.equals(Object)` instead of `==` to compare `String`s.

Comment: that is not the issue - the if statement works - its running another class inside a class which is the problem.

Comment: @user2418790 What do you mean by "running a class"?  Do you mean declaring a class? Instantiating a class? Running a (static or member) method of a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If coded correctly then what your asking to do in your question would be able to work just fine!

```
String ans = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "S,T,R,K or P?");
if (ans.equals("S"))
{ 
    Square s = new Square();
}
```

Square Class

```
public class Square {
//bla bla bla
}
```